# use of .ToList().AsQueryable()

Tags: linq-to-sql

I came across linq query which ends in (...).ToList().AsQueryable(). I know the use of .ToList() and .AsQueryable() separately. But, what is the outcome if both are combined? When do we need to combine them? I hope this question is not too dump question. Thanks in advance.

First query:

```
Dim costAmounts = (From t In model.OrderTrades                            
Join o In model.Orders On t.OrdNum Equals o.OrdNum 
Where o.ClientCode = clientNumber And o.BookDate = sysrec.ETicketsBookDate
Group t By t.Buy, t.OrdNum Into Amount = Sum(t.BuyAmount) _
Select OrdNum = OrdNum, Currency = Buy, SellAmount = Amount).ToList().AsQueryable()
```

Second Query:

```
 Dim orders = (From a In costAmounts _
                    Group Join s In settlements On s.Currency Equals a.Currency _
                        And s.OrdNum Equals a.OrdNum Into amounts = Group _
                    From g In amounts.DefaultIfEmpty _
                    Where g Is Nothing OrElse a.SellAmount - g.Paid <> 0 _
                    Select OrdNum = a.OrdNum Distinct).ToList()
```

Comment: This is probably the reason it's there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: @Ray: I posted an answer that explains why it does server a purpose, yet a strange once perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never need to combine the two.

`AsQueryable` is there to give you lazy evaluation features, which the `ToList` completely negates.

So, the LINQ query is forced to be evaluated by `ToList`, then, the in memory list is converted to an `IQueryable` in order to allow... querying over it. Instead of constructing the query and only getting the results as needed.

Comment: @Oded This query result is used in next query. Is that the reason behind it?

Comment: @gmail user - possibly, but why use `ToList` to begin with? Just return the LINQ query - it should already be an `IQueryable`.

Comment: The only reason i could se, would be the answer i posted below. Not that it would be a good pattern, but ToList().AsQueryable() *will* break the delayed execution and still end up as a Queryable result again...

Comment: @gmail user - please _edit_ your question and add the queries to it, instead of in comments where it looks bad and people may miss it.

Comment: If I remove the ToList or AsQueryable I can't use the first query in the send one

Comment: Hi @Oded, would you mind spending some of your valuable time? Could you show me the best way to do this? May be with some code

Comment: @gmail user - You can simply use `.AsQueryable()` directly on the results of the LINQ query without going through `ToList()` first.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I got this error. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VB$AnonymousType_138`3[System.String,System.String,System.Decimal]] DefaultIfEmpty[VB$AnonymousType_138`3](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VB$AnonymousType_138`3[System.String,System.String,System.Decimal]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @gmail user - looks like LINQ to Entities doesn't like the `DefaultIfEmpty` call you have in the second query. Where is that coming from?

Comment: There is a similar query "settlements" as the first one. And there is a group join of "settlements" and first query. Sometimes "settlements" doesn't have rows. That's why the DefaultIfEmpty is used.

Comment: In my experience (a quite particular way of working to be fair) I VERY OFTEN .ToList().AsQueryable() the reasons I do this are 1. ToList() forces the query to execute (v. useful to "force" the pull from the DB, or other source and force it all into RAM) 2. AsQueryable() gives ability to use various extensions and other methods, e.g. LinqKit's .And() / .Or() 3. The .ToList() often is required to avoid errors like @gmailusers "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" ec. So sorry but -1 as "You should never need to combine the two" is false. It's sometimes essential/very sensible.

Comment: Basic point is that assuming that lazy execution = good is NOT always a good assumption, if you know what's going on you might actually REQUIRE the execution to run at a particular time. e.g. query against the DB cannot "understand" some expression that relies on the data having been .ToList()'d and so projected into the entities so that said expression can run.

Answer (score 1):

The .ToList() would break the delayed execution which is often very helpful (passing queryables around will defer the execution, but could end up actually doing several executions later instead, if passed to multiple classes or methods). Once you do .AsQueryable() you then return the result as Queryable which might be a requirement.

EDIT: If we can agree that calling .ToList() on a queryable, and then pass the list around is the right pattern for some uses (i can really speed up your application in cases where your queryables explode into multiple variations, *each* needed to be executed at some point). If you break the delayed execution at some point your queries from there will be simplified and faster - then calling .AsQueryable() later would only serve the purpose of fitting the result to a specific (perhaps needed for some api) type.

Comment: if the requirement is to return a non-deferred queryable, you should probably change the requirement rather than the code

Comment: @Robert Levy: So true, if you can :P I'm not saying the pattern .ToList().AsQueryable() is good, just trying to explain a reason for using it